# Организация работы распределенного Git

Tags: git, сервер

Добрый день, вопрос такой:

Начал с коллегой использовать распределенный git, пока 
самым кустарным способом: на моей рабочей станции создали 
расшаренную папку, там  git репозитарий, и используем его 
как сервер по http.

1) Когда я на "сервере" создаю новую ветку ( после того, как
мы уже клонировали реп с сервера), то информация об этом
не появляется в клиентских копиях.

Т.е. клонировали репозитарий с веткой master, потом я создал 
на "сервере" ветки last и stable, additional, и хочу, чтобы
клиенты могли push/pull в last, pull из stable и не могли 
видеть additional.

Но в итоге, клиент ( как и следовало ожидать) не оповещается
об новых ветках, но зная их названия может иметь полный 
доступ во все ветки.

Т.е. вопрос в том, можно ли штатным гитом настроить права, 
видимость, оповещения клиента о новых ветках?

2) Если ответ на 1 вопрос отрицательный, то есть ли 
какой-нибудь дистрибутив, который позволит иметь все то,
что описано выше?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

> Начал с коллегой использовать распределенный git, пока самым кустарным способом: на моей рабочей станции создали расшаренную папку, там git репозитарий, и используем его как сервер по http.

а зачем каталог расшаривать? незачем.

> Когда я на "сервере" создаю новую ветку ( после того, как мы уже клонировали реп с сервера), то информация об этом не появляется в клиентских копиях.

Если кому то нужна ветка с сервера - просто клонирует себе.

> и хочу, чтобы клиенты могли push/pull в last, pull из stable и не могли видеть additional.

не хотите, что  бы другие видели Вашу ветку - не публикуйте ее. Это правильный способ.

> оповещения клиента о новых ветках?

Это можно. В git есть [hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). (на русском [немножко](http://habrahabr.ru/post/75063/)). К примеру можно отправлять по почте. Если сильно нужно, то можно хоть по jabber/icq присылать. Можно клиенту прислать набор команд, которые ему нужно выполнить, что бы ветку себе получить.

> Т.е. вопрос в том, можно ли штатным гитом настроить права, видимость,

видимость не знаю, а вот на запись - это можно. Есть такой хук - [update](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) - он получает три параметра, два с которых - ветка и имя пользователя. В зависимости от того, что возвратит скрипт, можно отсечь push в ветку. Сделать на этом систему ограничения прав - легко.

То есть, изучаем хуки, делаем на их базе свою систему разграничения.